# Add code to page template on page built with Visual Composer

Tags: plugins

I have built a page in Visual Composer, with some code written directly in the page template-file. But the code isn't loaded or visible in the source code front end. If I change to the Classic Editor the page template loads fine, with the page template-code there.

Is there a way to avoid that, loading the Visual Composer-built contant within a container, keeping the remaining template-content? And is Visual Composer in fact supposed to override the page template file completely?

What I know so far is that the correct page template is being used, both in Visual Composer and Classic Editor:

```
<body class="home page-template page-template-page-templates page-template-page-full-width">
```

The template itself looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Full Width
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div class="hovedmeny" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:red;z-index:10000;">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/featured-image' ); ?>
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-grid">
        <main class="main-content-full-width">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-vegan', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();
```

When I build pages with Visual Composer all this content is ignored, with no trace of `.hovedmeny` or `.main-container`

Any ideas?

Comment: Visual Composer has no control over the page templates at all. Basically all it is doing is changing the way that the post content is output. If you look in the template-parts folder in the content-vegan-page.php file you should find 'the_content()'. Are you sure you don't have two files with the template name set to 'Full Width'? I'd check this first. The other thing is to make sure any caching plugins are disabled while working on it.

Comment: @Erbilacx Well, after playing around with Visual Composer for a little while, I've been able to narrow it down a little. There aren't more page templates with the same name, and it's loading the right one. But as soon as I enable header/footer, the content of the page template evaporates. It's still gone if I turn header/footer off again. The only remaining evidence of the page templates existence, is the class in <body>. Strange.

Comment: @Erbilacx ..and setting it back to 'Theme Default' brings the content back again. I guess it's wanted behaviour, then. And global headers and footers are a no go in my project.

Comment: It sounds more like a theme issue than anything else.